# do a little change on a category book and upon chapters, sections etc

Tags: typography, books

I change my question. I've checked this : [How to color background header?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349786/how-to-color-background-header/349820#349820)

and in fact that's maybe what I want to do. To have a kind of box (like a banderolle) for the section and subsections... unfort. my code is globally well written in fancyhdr which is, I guess because it doesn't work for me, incompatible with titlesec.

Here is the settings for this :

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment} % pour les commentaires
\usepackage{lipsum}% juste utile ici pour générer du faux texte}
\usepackage{mwe}%juste utile ici pour générer de fausses images
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}%extensions de l'ams pour les mathématiques
\usepackage{dsfont} %fonction indicatrice
\usepackage{amsthm} %pour les théoremes
\usepackage{lmodern}    %celui ci et le suivant pour les boites
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{fancybox} %pour shadow box

\usepackage{shorttoc}%pour la réalisation d'un sommaire.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}%pour insérer images et pdf entre autres
    \graphicspath{{images/}}%pour spécifier le chemin d'accès aux images
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}%réglages des marges du document selon vos préférences ou celles de votre établissemant
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}%pour de jolis titres de chapitres voir la doc pour d'autres styles.

\usepackage{fancyhdr}%pour les entêtes et pieds de pages
    \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}% hauteur de l'entête


\usepackage{array}  %pour les array et binomes de newton 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%and i have added this line : 
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec} %pour redéfinir les headers



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%style front%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 
    \fancypagestyle{front}{%
        \fancyhf{}%on vide les entêtes
        \fancyfoot[C]{page \thepage}%
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%trait horizontal pour l'entête
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%trait horizontal pour les pieds de pages
        }


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%style main%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \fancypagestyle{main}{%
        \fancyhf{}
        \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ ##1}{}}% redéfintion pour avoir ici les titres des chapitres des sections en minuscules
        \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ ##1}}
        \fancyhead[c]{}
        \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\rightmark}%
        \fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
        \fancyfoot[C]{}
        \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{page \thepage}%
        \fancyfoot[LO,RE]{Mathématiques}
        }


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% and so i wanted to add those lines but it doesnt work...
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\newcommand{\ntl}{\newline \newline}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\fontsize{50}{60}\bfseries\color[rgb]{0,0.5,0.75}}{\thechapter\hsp\fontsize{90}{60}\selectfont\textcolor{black}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\thispagestyle{empty}\Huge\bfseries}

\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\textcolor[rgb]{0,0.5,0.75}{Topic \thesection} \ }[{\titlerule[0.8pt]}]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%






%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%style back%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
    \fancypagestyle{back}{%
        \fancyhf{}%on vide les entêtes
        \fancyfoot[C]{page \thepage}%
        \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%trait horizontal pour l'entête
        \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}%trait horizontal pour les pieds de pages
        }



\usepackage[english,french]{babel}%pour un document en français
\usepackage{hyperref}%rend actif les liens, références croisée, toc, ...
        \hypersetup{colorlinks,%
        citecolor=black,%
        filecolor=black,%
        linkcolor=gray,%
        urlcolor=blue}
```

do you have any idea how to have this taking account of those constraints?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it, but yes, it's possible. The `titlesec` package is the main tool to customise section titles.

Comment: why wouldn't you ? the aim is to make it clearer. It is not obvious that you're changing sections as it is for chapters

Comment: Typographically, it  reminds me of the times of typewriters.  It will look better to colour  titles   with some well chosen dark red or something of that kind (not ‘Cuisse de Nymphe Émue’, preferably…)

Comment: but the problem is that I d like to make it more obvious so just changing  the color isn't sufficient, maybe a color box?

Comment: You can have a coloured  background too (with `\fcolorbox`). But  I can assure you that a boldface title, with, say, IndianRed colour (it's defined  in the  `colors via svgnames option` section of the documentation of `xcolor`)  or IndianRed3 (`x11names option`) can't be missed.

Comment: and do you think that it is possible to increase the size of the titles ? that maybe chapter are biger, section also and finally subsection a little bit ?  and how can you make those changes ( with changing the color of the titles ? )

Comment: Please take a look at my answer to [How to colour background header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349786/how-to-color-background-header/349820#349820) to see an example use of `\titleformat` to obtain a resulting layout quite different from the LaTeX default.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't pile up questions. Go through your list of questions and consider to accept answers to them.

Comment: Excuse me @Bernard , can you check my question again ? i ve added precisions about it and about the code settings.

Comment: I'vejusty seen your code. Two observations *a priori* : you can't use both `fncychap` and `titlesec`: they tackle the same layout problem. Also `titleps` and `fancyhdr` are incompatible, for the same reason. Personally, with titlesec`, I prefer to use `titleps`, which furthermore is simpler to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with only `titlesec` and `titleps`. I modified some colours, in particular tho show you how to obtain a coloured section label (not title):

```
\documentclass[english,french]{book}%

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}%pour un document en français
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment} % pour les commentaires
\usepackage{lipsum}% juste utile ici pour générer du faux texte}
\usepackage{mwe}%juste utile ici pour générer de fausses images
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}%extensions de l'ams pour les mathématiques
\usepackage{dsfont} %fonction indicatrice
\usepackage{amsthm} %pour les théoremes
\usepackage{lmodern} %celui ci et le suivant pour les boites
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{fancybox} %pour shadow box
\usepackage{shorttoc}%pour la réalisation d'un sommaire.
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}%pour insérer images et pdf entre autres
    \graphicspath{{images/}}%pour spécifier le chemin d'accès aux images
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm, vmargin=4cm, headheight = 15pt]{geometry}%réglages des marges du document selon vos préférences ou celles de votre établissement
\usepackage{array} %pour les array et binômes de Newton

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%and i have added this line :
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec} %pour redéfinir les headers, les entête et les pieds-de-page
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%style front%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newpagestyle{main}{%
\headrule
\sethead[\thesection~\sectiontitle][][\chaptername\,\thechapter.\enspace\chaptertitle]%
{\chaptername\,\thechapter.\enspace\chaptertitle}{}{\thesection~\sectiontitle}
\setfoot[page\,\thepage][][Mathématiques]{Mathématiques}{}{page\,\thepage}
}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{%
\footrule
\sethead{}{}{}
\setfoot[page\,\thepage][][Mathématiques]{Mathématiques}{}{page\,\thepage}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% and so i wanted to add those lines but it doesnt work...
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\newcommand{\ntl}{\newline \newline}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\fontsize{50}{60}\bfseries\color{SteelBlue!5!DodgerBlue}}{\thechapter\hsp\fontsize{90}{60}\selectfont\textcolor{DarkSlateGrey! 5!SteelBlue}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\thispagestyle{empty}\Huge\bfseries}

\titleformat{\section}{\large\bfseries}{\rlap{\color{AliceBlue}\rule[-1.25ex]{\textwidth}{4ex}}\textcolor{Mahogany}{~Topic \thesection}}{1em}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{hyperref}%rend actif les liens, références croisée, toc, ...{0,0.5,0.75}
 \hypersetup{colorlinks,%
 citecolor=black,%
 filecolor=black,%
 linkcolor=gray,%
 urlcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{main}

\chapter{A First Chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\section{A wonderful topic}
\lipsum[3-4]

\subsection{Some subtopic}

\lipsum[5-25]

 \end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: this is astonishing ! thank you ! can you tell me what does \rule does? "\rule[-1.25ex]"

Comment: \rule displays the ‘banderole’, as you say. It has a total height of 4ex, is is lowered bt 1.25ex, for vertical centring reasons. B.t.w., I forgot to mention it, but your front and back pagestyles are the same, so I defined  a single equivaleny=t style with `titleps`, to which I gave a  semantically neutral name, `plain` (it's only a variation on the default plain style).

Answer (score 0):

The option `pagestyles` tells `titlesec` to load `titleps` for headers and footers but you use `fancyhdr` instead.
You could switch to `titleps` but it is easier to just delete this option.
So instead of

```
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
```

you just have to write

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
```

This fixes the error but you should also delete `\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}`. `fncychap` would normally change the `\chapter` style but the change is overwritten by `\titleformat{\chapter}`, so `fncychap` does not have any effect.